# Fedora stopped booting after freeing up space

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

I have dual boot PC. I installed Fedora on my system a long time ago. I didn't use it much then and thus, I allocated 20 GB of space for that OS. Recently, I need to complete a project on React, and I saw most of tutorials using Linux distributions for this purpose. So I started working on Fedora again.

The problem arose when a low space notification started to appear. I needed to clear the space and hence I Googled the solution and tried to free up space. But I went into trouble when I deleted some important file from the system, which I have no idea of. I usually take proper precautions before taking some steps but due to bad luck or something, I thought things should work well and went wrong way. After deleting some files, I noticed that system started working very slowly. Later, when I restarted Fedora, it stuck into the bubble icon and didn't boot further. I understood I got into a huge trouble. Then, by chance, I clicked arrow down key and got to see the log report (which I am uploading with my question).

[image: error_image1]

[image: error_image2]

It had too many failure statements. I saw one thing in common and that was some reference to - systemctl.

I have created live USB of latest Fedora from my windows. I am able to access my files, but not the other react applications. I need to solve the problem by restoring files. Solution that provide backing up my Fedora data would also be helpful since I can then reinstall Fedora.

Comment: I always have two partitions, one for `/` and one for `/home`, that way I can reinstall the OS without having to restore `/home`. I also use `etckeeper` to revision control `/etc`. Use the live distro to backup `/home` and `/etc` reinstall, recover `/home` (don't recover `/etc`, but use the backup to recover stuff as needed).

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall Linux?
Copy your important files before reinstall with a help of `RescueCD` - or like that.

Comment: what I usually do in this kind of case is 1) boot from a live cd 2) mount your disk 3) chroot into it 4) reinstall all packages. Works well on rolling-releases, and is at least good to try on fedora

Answer (score 2):

You can just run the Fedora installer from your USB stick. It will detect the existing Fedora installation and upgrade it (and in the process should restore it to working order by replacing the missing packages).